# Insert Data in ssms table with c#

Tags: c#-4.0, ssms-2014

im quite new to programming and c#/ssms and i wanted to insert data into a table i created in ssms with a program in c#.
So this is my code right now. it works somehow, but it doesnt insert the data into the table in ssms. The part above "myConnection.Open();" is fine, its just about the rest.

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, myConnection))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Artikel (Artikelnummer, Bezeichnung, Lieferant, Einkaufspreis, Verkaufspreis, Rabatt) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "', '" + textBox6.Text + "')");
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
```

hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you get any error?

Comment: I think you should not use the:
SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Artikel (Artikelnummer, Bezeichnung, Lieferant, Einkaufspreis, Verkaufspreis, Rabatt) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "', '" + textBox6.Text + "')");

And that should be before in the myCommand because you're using twice the same sentence.

Comment: 1. What is your question? You provide no error information or relevant information. 2. You have 2 `SqlCommand` instances. 3. Always use parameters, not string concatenation. See also [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements)

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injection](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection). What happens if one of your articles happens to be a musketeer costume... maybe even that of `D'Artagnan`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not executing this sentence:

```
SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Artikel (Artikelnummer, Bezeichnung, Lieferant, Einkaufspreis, Verkaufspreis, Rabatt) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "', '" + textBox6.Text + "')");
```

Because you declared the variable before with a different name:

```
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, myConnection))
```

In order to work, you firstly need to declare the SQL Statement and later execute it:

```
string sqlStatement = "Insert Into Artikel (Artikelnummer, Bezeichnung, Lieferant, Einkaufspreis, Verkaufspreis, Rabatt) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "', '" + textBox6.Text + "')";

using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, myConnection))
    {
        myConnection.Open();


        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

I think it should work with this change. Also, for the near future, I recommend you **Entity Framework**, it's going to help you a lot in your programming career:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/

Also, you should avoid this code and you are going to avoid [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you can do something like this:

```
string sqlStatement = "Insert Into Artikel (Artikelnummer, Bezeichnung, Lieferant, Einkaufspreis, Verkaufspreis, Rabatt) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5, @val6)";

using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, myConnection))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = textBox1.Text ?? (object) System.DBNull.Value});
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = textBox2.Text ?? (object) System.DBNull.Value});
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = textBox3.Text ?? (object) System.DBNull.Value});
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val4", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = textBox4.Text ?? (object) System.DBNull.Value});
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val5", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = textBox5.Text ?? (object) System.DBNull.Value});
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val6", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = textBox6.Text ?? (object) System.DBNull.Value});

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```